# Accessing canvas element without "getElementById"

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

It seems with this example the usual "var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");" to access the canvas is not required for the code to make a square.

Is there any downside to leaving this out (from a minify-ing perspective)?

Example taken from [here](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Html/Elements/canvas)

Tested on chrome, IE and firefox

```js
//var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var canvasContext = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
canvasContext.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300">
Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Canvas element.
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the id causes the canvas to be considered a "named 
element", a behaviour described in [HTML standards](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object). For each named element, the browser defines a corresponding global property on the `document` object, in this case `myCanvas`. you could similarly access `document.myCanvas`.

Apart from the fact that using `var` is much, much less ambiguous and confusing, this behaviour is inconsistent on older versions of IE. Using the global variable is neither faster nor more optimized so there really is no reason to use it.

To answer your exact question, there should be no issues from a minifying perspective

Comment: It's not 1999 anymore. You can't use older versions of IE as an excuse.
Just embrace this nice simplicity-feature.
If you use 'window.myCanvas' it's not even ambiguous, but a super indicator. And you should use 'const' for this, not 'var'. And you are wrong, 'window.myCanvas' actually is the fastest way.